# Using Google Auth in Development

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, next.js, google-oauth, google-authentication

I recently submitted a verification request to have a public Google OAuth Client and with that I had to remove my localhost URIs and callbacks. I've tried to figure out what the best way for using Google Auth in development is but couldn't find a definite solution.

Does anybody have insights by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

The best option you will have would be to create a second project to use in development.  Then use the verified one for production.

This solves any problems you may have if you are testing something that would require you to change scopes.  If you change the scopes used in your production application chances are it will have to go though verification again.  So having a test app is the best solution i have come up with.